# How to detect seasonality in data in R?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, seasonality, adjustment

My goal is to (1) prove the hypothesis of seasonality in this inflation time-series and (2) remove the seasonality via the X-13-ARIMA-SEATS procedure.

My questions are (1) how does one prove such hypothesis and (2) how does one know if the procedure has worked.

The code:

```
 if (!require("tis")) {install.packages("tis"); library('tis')} # Load time series library
    if (!require("seasonal")) {install.packages("seasonal"); library('seasonal')}

inflation.start <- c(1960,1)
inflation.end <- c(2018,1)

inflation.raw <- "rawData/germany_inflation.csv"
inflation.table <- read.table(inflation.raw, skip = 1, header = F, sep = ',', stringsAsFactors = F)
inflation.ger <- ts(inflation.table[,2], start = inflation.start, frequency = 4)

ts.plot(inflation.ger) # plot
acf(inflation.ger) # auto-correlation

inflation.seasadj <- final(seas(as.ts(naWindow(inflation.ger),freq=4))) # seasonal adjustment
inflation.seasadj.ger <- ts(inflation.seasadj, start = inflation.start, frequency = 4)
```

The data:

```
dput(inflation.ger)
structure(c(2.22222222222224, 1.244019138756, 0.75973409306742, 
1.80608365019013, 1.98487712665404, 2.64650283553874, 2.73327049952876, 
3.36134453781511, 3.15106580166824, 2.39410681399631, 2.47706422018348, 
3.25203252032522, 2.87511230907457, 2.42805755395685, 3.31244404655327, 
2.27471566054242, 2.09606986899562, 2.72168568920105, 2.2530329289428, 
2.05303678357573, 3.07955517536358, 3.84615384615386, 3.98305084745763, 
4.10729253981556, 4.06639004149377, 3.04526748971191, 2.93398533007336, 
2.49597423510466, 1.8341307814992, 1.75718849840257, 1.10847189231985, 
1.49253731343286, 1.25293657008615, 1.33437990580847, 1.80109631949884, 
1.62538699690402, 2.01082753286931, 2.09140201394268, 1.92307692307691, 
2.89413556740292, 3.33586050037907, 3.5660091047041, 4.00000000000001, 
4.44115470022204, 5.06236243580337, 5.78754578754579, 5.66037735849054, 
5.31537916371368, 4.88826815642457, 5.47091412742381, 6.25000000000001, 
6.46029609690444, 7.39014647137152, 6.9599474720946, 7.30446024563674, 
7.45891276864728, 7.06757594544325, 6.99815837937383, 6.44578313253009, 
5.88235294117648, 6.25361899247252, 6.08146873207113, 5.43293718166383, 
5.22222222222223, 4.30517711171662, 3.78583017847487, 3.70370370370372, 
3.80147835269271, 3.81400208986417, 3.85617509119333, 3.46790890269152, 
3.00101729399797, 2.86864620030195, 2.50878073256398, 2.50125062531265, 
2.91358024691356, 3.27788649706457, 4.650024473813, 5.31966813079548, 
5.51823416506719, 5.92136428233066, 5.19176800748362, 5.14365152919371, 
5.72987721691677, 5.81395348837209, 6.66963094708762, 7.13970912296167, 
5.89247311827958, 5.36770921386304, 5.08545227177989, 4.648292883587, 
4.06173842404549, 3.28920978740473, 3.13367711225704, 2.71226415094341, 
2.84933645589384, 2.83495145631071, 1.88461538461538, 2.06659012629162, 
2.31499051233397, 2.30362537764349, 2.076255190638, 1.57480314960629, 
0.741839762611279, 0, -0.332840236686399, -0.922849760059066, 
-0.515463917525782, 0.0369139904023732, 0.519480519480511, 0.968703427719836, 
0.962250185048109, 1.14391143911439, 1.29198966408267, 1.69741697416972, 
2.4193548387097, 2.88215979569498, 2.80612244897959, 3.01161103047896, 
2.72011453113812, 2.3049645390071, 2.72952853598016, 3.02923564635434, 
2.84251480582282, 3.29915972330998, 4.51351791825871, 5.50437317784258, 
5.9108527131783, 6.09404990403073, 4.95750708215298, 3.33642261353105, 
4.66605672461115, 4.38715513342377, 4.5434098065677, 4.30493273542601, 
2.97202797202796, 2.77296360485268, 2.58175559380379, 2.45055889939811, 
2.07979626485568, 1.7284991568297, 1.5520134228188, 1.46873688627781, 
1.45530145530146, 1.45047658516367, 1.36307311028499, 1.53019023986766, 
1.76229508196721, 1.55228758169937, 2.32273838630808, 2.11812627291242, 
1.24848973016513, 1.36765888978277, 0.597371565113501, 0.438771439968094, 
0.198886237072386, 0.515873015873038, 0.673000791765629, 0.953137410643369, 
1.54823342596267, 1.10540860639556, 1.37632717263074, 1.73092053501181, 
1.72009382329947, 2.53807106598985, 2.01706749418153, 1.6627996906419, 
1.99846272098384, 1.29474485910129, 1.21673003802282, 1.17915557246102, 
1.13036925395631, 0.789473684210527, 1.05184072126221, 1.16541353383457, 
0.968703427719814, 1.86497575531517, 1.82156133828996, 2.0066889632107, 
1.62361623616237, 1.24496521420726, 1.64293537787514, 1.67577413479055, 
1.70660856935367, 1.84448462929475, 1.4727011494253, 1.28986026513793, 
1.7850767583006, 2.05965909090908, 2.26548672566371, 3.0774672798019, 
2.94633461943178, 2.88796102992346, 3.08065074420214, 1.61290322580647, 
0.81771720613288, 0.270544470747383, -0.235057085292139, 0.405268490374862, 
0.811084825954715, 1.11298482293424, 1.11073712554695, 1.37907837201482, 
1.87730472678512, 2.00133422281521, 2.19707057256989, 2.22295952222959, 
2.13886146758801, 1.86396337475473, 2.01954397394136, 2.01233365790325, 
1.54639175257732, 1.50882825040129, 1.62835249042147, 1.33630289532296, 
1.20558375634519, 1.07526881720429, 0.848256361922726, 0.50235478806906, 
0.0313479623824208, 0.469336670838559, 0.124610591900319, 0.312402374258052, 
0.250705108116592, 0.0934288383680993, 0.466708151835709, 1.12114606041732, 
1.87558612066271, 1.68014934660859, 1.73428305977082, 1.66307360640589, 
1.50352868978214), .Tsp = c(1960, 2017.75, 4), class = "ts")
```

Comment: You could plot the autocorrelation function (acf) and see if there's a spike at 12 month gaps, which would suggest seasonality.

Answer (score 3):

##### Use the `spectrum.test` function in the `ts.extend` package

A reasonable first step here would be to fit a linear regression model using time (numeric) and quarter (categorical) as explanatory variables.  You can then use an ANOVA to determine whether there is evidence of the quarter affecting the inflation rate.  You can also plot the residuals to see what is left-over once you remove the trend and any quarter-seasonality.

```
#Set up data
n    <- length(inflation.ger)
TIME <- 1:n
QTR  <- rep(c('Qtr1', 'Qtr2', 'Qtr3', 'Qtr4'), times = n/4)
DATA <- data.frame(Inflation = c(inflation.ger),
                   Time      = TIME,
                   Quarter   = QTR)

#Fit regression model
MODEL <- lm(Inflation ~ Time + factor(Quarter), data = DATA)
RESID <- MODEL$residuals

#Plot residuals
plot(RESID, ylim = c(-5,5), type = 'l',
     xlab = 'Time', ylab = 'Inflation Residual')

#Examine ANOVA
anova(MODEL)

    Analysis of Variance Table

Response: Inflation
                 Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
Time              1 170.13 170.134 67.5025 1.601e-14 ***
factor(Quarter)   3   0.03   0.011  0.0042    0.9996    
Residuals       227 572.13   2.520                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

[image]

From the ANOVA we see that there is no evidence of an effect for the quarter variable (i.e., no evidence of an annual seasonal effect).  However, the residuals in the plot show some clear "waves" that are indicative of seasonality.  To test formally for seasonality in the residuals we can plot the intensity in the Fourier domain and perform a permutation-spectrum test ([O'Neill 2021](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.05798), [O'Neill 2021](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.12416)).  From the output below you can see that there is strong evidence for the presence of one or more signals ($p=4 \times 10^{-6}$).

```
#Conduct permutation-spectrum test
TEST <- ts.extend::spectrum.test(RESID)
plot(TEST)
TEST

    Permutation-Spectrum Test

data:  real time-series vector RESID with 232 values
maximum scaled intensity = 4.6728, p-value = 4e-06
alternative hypothesis: distribution of time-series vector is not exchangeable
(at least one periodic signal is present)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can see the seasonality here:

```
plot(decompose(inflation.ger))
```

Different goods may have different seasonal effects that make the aggregated view less telling.  Consider breaking the price data into certain goods and see if you can find more pronounced effects there.

Comment: Hi Ryan, we talked at StackExchange. I am guessing that although the uploader labelled the data as 'seasonally unadjusted', the seasonal component is so small that he/she might have labelled it as 'seasonally adjusted', correct? Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea. It could just be a force of habit as a disclaimer.